# AAD authentification in AKS

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI package.
And simple authentication in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Everything works fine if I publish application to Azure Web App. But my application is inside Docker container and is located in AKS. External LoadBalancer working fine, but doesn't have SSL option. That's why I have tried to configure Front Door or Application Gateway. With no luck. 
When I am using Gateway and setting reply URL to **https**://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/signin-oidc I am receiving

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application

When to **http**://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/signin-oidc

> AADSTS500117: The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a
>   secure scheme.

Similar story with Front Door and if to remove app.UseHsts() and app.UseHttpsRedirection()

Comment: just use ingress with ssl offloading?

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal? It may be useful.

Comment: @4c74356b41, I have previously tried nginx with same result. And have a long conversation with support with no result. Last thing that I have get from them is that I am using nginx and I should use service from MSFT. 
ALFA, thank you for link. That's exactly what I am using now

Comment: better use ingress - its much better than application gateway, which is a beta ingress for k8s

Comment: you need to use ingress for ssl offloading. Use let's encrypt for ease of use. you would find certificates.yaml, certissuer.yaml files online. assign public address a custom domain and deploy above yaml files for that custom domain mapped. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after all my troubles with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI + Kubernetes I have decided to use [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code)